# Column Data added to another worksheet as Row Data with selected information

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a spreadsheet in Google that has data in columns with the headers in the ROW.

```
Column A              Column B                   Column C
                       Ticked                     Ticket  
Property Info        Property 1                 Property 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Address:           23 London Road            35 Manchester Road
Price:                £25,000                    £10,000
Rent:                 £500pcm                    £350pcm
Yield:                 50%                         35%
```

I want the be able to tick a box in google sheets and the information required to be added to another spreadsheet as a row like this:

```
Address                Price          Rent          Yield
-----------------------------------------------------------------
23 London Road        £25,000        £500pcm         50%
35 Manchester Road    £10,000        £350pcm         35%
```

I have tried using `QUERY` to pivot the data but that doesn't work. 
I have also tried using `HLookup` but that doesn't work either.

Is there a better way without programming the events in?

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hMXotK8mtUt2RSqhZrWaTvz52xg-6-W0CRxwpKh5eWI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Data!A:D), 
 "where not Col1 = FALSE", 1), 
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5", 1)
```

[image: 0]